# Angular.js ng-style fails to emit css styles related to element's height

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

`ng-style` is supposed to emit html `style` attributes based on styles defined via JSON. For example:

```
 <div ng-style='{"background-color":"yellow", "height":"500px;"}'></div>
```

should compile into something like:

```
 <div style='background-color:yellow; height:500px;'>
```

Now the problem is that it works for some css styles like `background-color` but does not work for some others like  `height` . Here is a live demo:
http://plnkr.co/edit/DACbF0GHU7LweBL9poka?p=preview
Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in Angular?

PS. This question is not about whether inline styles are a good idea. Things like bar charts require binding height to dynamic data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the semicolon after `500px`. Should be:

```
<div ng-style='{"background-color":"yellow", "height":"500px"}'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Ian! I can't believe I did not notice the semicolon myself! PS. Would you agree that it would be a lot nicer if Angular threw an exception instead of just silently ignoring the data that I am sending to it?

Comment: @DennisKashkin Actually, Angular isn't ignoring it. If you inspect the element, you can see that Angular emits the style just fine, but the *browser* ignores it. It wouldn't really make sense for Angular to have a full CSS-checker built-in, since things change so fast and different browsers do different things. Angular is doing the simplest thing here, which is probably for the best.